# ASP DDL jquery selector

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ddl

The drop down lists IDs get modified when the control is handled by the server so instead of SimpleDDL they become cph_main_SimpleDDL or something like that.

I have a jQuery method that takes the DDL ID, but it doesn't work as the DDL names change.

What JS function can I use to split the ID name and get just the SimpleDDL part?

I know how to select this particular part of the name by doing this:

```
$('select[id$=SimpleDDL]')
```

but I need to just get a part of the ID name and assign it to a variable.

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. In .NET when we use master page Id of control changes as you mentioned so we can get ID of control like `'<%=SimpleDDL.ClientID %>'`
2. If you are using .NET 4.0 then there is an property of control `ClientIDMode="static"` so this will remain you control id as mentioned.